# How to add custom className in React Hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to add custom className in ReactJs Hooks component. Please find code below.

`<i className='owf owf-200'></i>`

So basically I want variable let num = 200 which change my integer.
My code will look like below

`<i className={owf owf-${200}}></i>`

Can anyone find a solution? because this is not a stateful component hence I am finding difficulties here.

Thanks for the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (back-ticks)

```js
let num = 200
<i className={`owf owf-${num}`}/>
```

Comment: Thank you! I did the same using template literal but unfortunately, I did tick outside of the parenthesis.

Anyway. I am thankful to you for saving my day.

Comment: glad to hear its working .... please consider to accept the answer if you like..

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: please [see here for info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow)

Comment: Done mate. Thank you. I am happy to learn this. Have great time ahead